# Pandas: Group by the first two characters of the row index of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

The row indexes for my Pandas dataframe (df) are `[0015, 0030, 0045, 0100, 0115, 0130, 0145, 0200, 0215, 0230.....2345]`

How do I group by the **first two elements of the index** using `df.groupby.['TIME']` (Where 'TIME" is the column title for my row index)?

ie. I want to group by `[00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05,.......23]`

Comment: Why not extract the first two characters to a new column, and group on that? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: What is the dtype of df.index?  I assume object (strings).

Comment: I already am creating quite a number of columns.  I didn't want to add another column.  I have researched but haven't found any that talk about splitting an index.

Comment: The index is of type string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str[:2]).sum()
```

use the string accessor with index slicing.